# Are Cross-site scripting attacks relevant with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xss

I'm building a React app, with PHP(Codeigniter) backend.

Being that Codeigniter does't seem to take care of this issue automatically, i started exploring the subject. I understand why user input must be escaped, before rendered in an HTML page, but the question is, whether this should be done in an app that relies solely on AJAX.

I've tried outputting this string inside an HTML element in a React component, after being received via ajax request:

```
<script>alert('hey');</script>
```

It ended up as just a literal string in the HTML. Of course, no JS was executed.

Are there some situations, where such a string can be executed, even though it was extracted from an ajax JSON?

Comment: Browser stops it from executing.

Comment: Praveen: So can i ignore the issue completely?

Comment: I really believe so. Do you have an instance where you include a script this way from a different domain and it gets executed?

Comment: Nope, i don't. But i'm also inexperienced..

Comment: I am going to leave this as is. Let's wait for answers from other experts.

Comment: Most humble thing i've read on this site :D

Comment: Ha ha... I didn't understand? Sorry, what you meant?

Comment: I mean, it's uncommon to see modesty on this site :-)

Comment: Okay, just got some info for you. As far as I know, the browser when it requests AJAX content from a different site, it will be considered as a Cross Site Scripting or XSS. When browser suspects that this might be potentially vulnerable to the user and that is also from another domain other than the current domain, it ceases the execution of JavaScript or similar stuff. `:)` So I really believe it's safe with the modern browsers, but I am really not sure with the old ones, if you are targeting them. `:)`

Comment: I see. One thing to mention: my backend API isn't on a different domain. The server that serves the files, is the same one that acts as an API

Comment: Have you considered using Cross Origin? Check out http://Enable-CORS.com and that might take you to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to escap tags at backend before sending it to frontend.

Lets take an example:

Let us assume you call http://example.com/get.php?userInput=< script >alert('hi');< /script >

Expected output of above request is "< script >alert('hi');< /script >".

Now the ajax call is converting it into string literal and it is not being executed at the place where it is being consumed but if user directly visit the above url it will be rendered as HTML and above script will be executed. In this case attacked might still be able to steal cookie or do other malicious work.

Comment: Very interesting example...didn't think about it

Comment: Many times, especially with modern single-page applications, it is an anti-pattern to implement encoding on the server. Most of the times it's better to send data to the client as is (encoded to the transfer format, ie. json, obviously), and then the client can decide what further encoding it needs depending on where it will be used. The point is that it is not necessarily html encoding, and the server should have no way to know. Of course, partial html should be escaped. If content-type is text/json and x-content-type-options: nosniff is sent, direct access will not be vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you take `Cross Site Scripting (CSS)` differently, `CSS` could not be prevented automatically by any kind programming language. Actually, in `CSS` javascript code has been stored in database and get rendered while displaying, stored code may have ajax call and send to data to some other site with your cookies data.

There will not be any problem if you print stored code as it is. If you print your json value like `echo json_enocde($apiArray)` then your will code not be executed even if your api called without ajax(by hitting url) because script code is getting hidden in browser (you can check it out).

Yes, your code can be executed if you bind your ajax return value as HTML. That's why javascript frameworks print ajax returned values as it is and you have to write code explicitly to bind html code. If you bind your ajax value.

see [how to bind html in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063291/reactjs-dynamic-html-binding-values-to-the-child-class) in this case your code can be executed.

In php there is - `htmlentities($values_that_need_to_be_printed_with_script_tag)` function that prints your code as it is, this does not allow the browsers to render javascript code.

The simple thing to prevent `CSS(corss site scripting)` is print your data as it is - don't allow your browser to render your code stored in database.

Comment: let me know whether it is helpful to you or not? if not i will provide you more resources.

Comment: Hmm, i'm still a bit confused about it :D